# Firebase nested query on timestamp range

Tags: javascript, firebase, timestamp

I am having issues with nested queries:

```
firebase.database().ref().child('panels').child('qa')
      .orderByChild('completed')
      .startAt(firstDay.getTime()) // January 1st, 2016
      .endAt(lastDay.getTime()) // current date (aug, 25th 2016)
      .once('value', function(snapshot) {
        $log.log(snapshot.numChildren());
      });
```

returns 0

If I place completed in first level of node it works:

```
firebase.database().ref().child('panels')
      .orderByChild('completed')
      .startAt(firstDay.getTime()) // January 1st, 2016
      .endAt(lastDay.getTime()) // current date (aug, 25th 2016)
      .once('value', function(snapshot) {
        $log.log(snapshot.numChildren());
      });
```

returns 10;

Any ideas why the nested solution does not work?

Answer (score 0):

Ok the problem was:

```
   firebase.database().ref().child('panels')
    .orderByChild('qa/completed')
    .startAt(firstDay.getTime()) // January 1st, 2016
    .endAt(lastDay.getTime()) // current date (aug, 25th 2016)
    .once('value', function(snapshot) {
      $log.log(snapshot.numChildren());
    });
```

you have to orderByChild the nested data